# AngularJS/Jasmine: $http.get not working for the test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Something strange is happening in jasmine. My code is working in Angular but when I execute $http.get in jasmin it is not working.

My factory is

```
app.factory('LocalizationHandler', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var self = this;

    var res = {
        SetNewCulture: function (culture)
        {
            console.log("Inside SetNewCulture");

            self.culture = culture;

            var res = "";
            var defer = $q.defer();


            $http.get("Scripts/Lib/Factories/Localization/CookinConcepts.json").success(function (response)
            {
                console.log("estoy dentro");
                defer.resolve(response);
                return defer.promise;
            }).
            error(function (e) {
                console.log("ERROR");
            }).
            then(function (response)
            {
                console.log("OKEY");
                self.LocalizationItems = response.data[self.culture]; 
            });

            return defer.promise;
        }
    }

    self.LocalizationConstructor = function () {
        res.SetNewCulture(res.GetCurrentCulture());
        self.LocalizationItems = null;
        self.culture = "ca-ES";

    };

    self.LocalizationConstructor();

    return res;
}]);
```

My test is:

```
/// <reference path="../../../_references.js" />

describe("Factory - LocalizationHandler", function () {
    var lh;

    beforeEach(module('appCookIn'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function (LocalizationHandler) {
            lh = LocalizationHandler;
        });
    });

    it("LocalizationHandler - SetNewCulture", function () {
        // Arrange
        var expected = "es-ES";
        // Act
        var result = lh.SetNewCulture("es-ES");

        // Assert
        expect(result).not.toBe(expected);
    });
});
```

with `console.log`I see only the next text in the OutPut window: `Inside SetNewCulture`.

SHOULD THE JSON FILE IN THE TEST PROJECT OR IN THE MAIN PROJECT?

Why in the test the function $http is not working? should geta json file with my culture?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: @David have you read the documentation about $httpBackend that JcT posted? It looks like you should create a mock HTTP endpoint for your test to hit that will return test data, that way you will get an actual response and be able to see what happens when you enter your success call.

Comment: yes SamHuckby, thx for it